# How to display the first tab in my Wordpress loop?

Tags: wordpress, tabs, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Wordpress and Foundation Tabs.

**Objective**:
 
To display Wordpress posts from a specific category in vertical Foundation tabs.

I currently have a static version displayed here:
 
http://www.aos-engineering.com (Under Projects)

**Problem**: 
 
On the page load, the first tab displayed is empty. However, when you click through the tabs, they display correctly.

**Question**
 
How do I display the fist tab item on the page load?

Here is a test page displaying the problem:
 
http://www.aos-engineering.com/test/

**Code**

```
<div class="full-width" id="projects">
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 medium-3 large-3 columns">          
        <dl class="tabs vertical profile-tabs" data-tab>
        <?php
         $displayposts = new WP_Query();
         $displayposts->query('category_name=Projects');
         while ($displayposts->have_posts()) : $displayposts->the_post();
         $tab_number = $displayposts->current_post + 1;             
          ?> 
          <dd><a href="#tab<?php echo $tab_number;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </dl>
    </div>  

    <div class="small-8 medium-9 large-9 columns">
        <div class="tabs-head">Projects</div>

        <div class="tabs-content">  
              <?php   
              while ($displayposts->have_posts()) : $displayposts->the_post();
              $tab_number = $displayposts->current_post + 1;
              ?> 
              <div class="content" id="tab<?php echo $tab_number;?>">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-9 large-9 columns">
                      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                      <p><small><?php the_field('img_caption'); ?></small></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="medium-3 large-3 columns">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>                      
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your code add the class `active` to the `.tabs > dl` and the `.tabs-content > div` you want displayed on page load.

Add this to the two lines after `$tab_number = ...` to have the first tab be the active tab on load:

```
$active_class = (1 == $tab_number) ? 'active' : '';
```

Then in the output:

```
<dd class="<?php echo $active_class;?>" ><a href=...
<div class="content <?php echo $active_class;?>"...
```

See the [Foundation Tabs documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hat tip **CPILKO** for the solution.

---

Here is how to display Wordpress posts from a specific category in vertical Foundation tabs.

- To display your posts, simply add your category name
   
  'category_name=YourCategoryName'

### Solution

```
<div class="full-width" id="projects">
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-4 medium-3 large-3 columns">          
        <dl class="tabs vertical profile-tabs" data-tab>
        <?php
         $displayposts = new WP_Query();
         $displayposts->query('category_name=Projects');
         while ($displayposts->have_posts()) : $displayposts->the_post();
         $tab_number = $displayposts->current_post + 1; 
         $active_class = (1 == $tab_number) ? 'active' : '';            
          ?> 
          <dd class="<?php echo $active_class;?>"><a href="#tab<?php echo $tab_number;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </dl>
    </div>  

    <div class="small-8 medium-9 large-9 columns">
        <div class="tabs-head">Projects</div>

        <div class="tabs-content">  
              <?php   
              while ($displayposts->have_posts()) : $displayposts->the_post();
              $tab_number = $displayposts->current_post + 1;
              $active_class = (1 == $tab_number) ? 'active' : ''; 
              ?> 
              <div class="content <?php echo $active_class;?>" id="tab<?php echo $tab_number;?>">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="medium-9 large-9 columns">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <p><small>Show above: Huiit Zolars</small></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="medium-3 large-3 columns">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```